# UICollectionView - Horizontal Tableview - Swift - Displaying different images in each row

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I put an UICollectionView inside a TableView for displaying images
horizontally. I want to add only 4 images per row and of course these images should be different in each row. My code so fa

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4;
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell

    var imageName:String?

    if(Constants.counter >= 1 && Constants.counter <= 4) {
        imageName = DataSource.eyeColorArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    }

    if(Constants.counter >= 5 && Constants.counter <= 8) {
        imageName = DataSource.maskArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)as? String
    }

    var concurrentQueue : dispatch_queue_t?
    concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue!) {
        let img = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        cell._imgView.image = img
    }
    Constants.counter = Constants.counter + 1
    print(Constants.counter)
    return cell
}
```

My attempt was to use a counter variable **Constants.counter** which helps me to pick images from different arrays every 4 steps. So this means.. In the beginning my first row gets images from the **DataSource.eyeColorArray**. In my second row the images are picked from my **DataSource.maskArray**.

The problem in that case is, that my first and second row is filled with the images which were picked from the last array (DataSource.maskArray)

Any ideas?
Best regards,
Nazar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what is triggering the behavior you see but your use of `Counter` here makes a number of unsafe assumptions about how `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called and I think you should avoid this approach.

As you load and scroll through a collection view `cellForItemAtIndexPath` can be called for every index path as it is displayed. It will be called more than once per index path. It can be called for index paths in ascending or descending order, it would be valid to call it for a set of index paths in any arbitrary order.

Your `Counter` causes the content of these cells to depend on the order and number of calls to `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. If you instead choose images based on the section and row of the index path argument you would have a much safer and more predictable implementation.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve my problem. I am using **Constants.counter** because when I try to access to **indexpath.section** I always get the value **0**. That is because I have an UICollectionViewCell inside my TableViewCell

Comment: Yes, your collection view index paths are independent of your table view index paths. If each cell needs additional information (like the section it currently belongs to) to correctly populate it's collection view you'll need to provide that data to each cell explicitly.

Comment: Yes, thats right. But I do not know how to do that. Where do I have to focus?

Comment: It depends on what you need; you might add a property to each table cell to allow you to set the section number or a reference to the array of pictures that cell should use and then set that property in the table view data source's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Jonah Jonah Jonah... You saved me =) Thanks a lot my friend. Very good advice